# Update multiple rows (with different ids and different values) using one query

Tags: 7, database

I want to update multiple rows in a custom table using just one query.

Each row has its own id (obviously) and different fields/values to update.

Given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query) and [this post](http://stuporglue.org/update-multiple-rows-at-once-with-different-values-in-mysql/), i think i can achieve it with a single `db_query`, similar to this one:

```
UPDATE {table} SET

`field1` = CASE `id`
    WHEN 1 THEN 'field1 value 1'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'field1 value 2'
    END

`field2` = CASE `id`
    WHEN 1 THEN 'field2 value 1'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'field2 value 2'
    END

WHERE `id` IN(1, 2);
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO {table} (`id`, `field1`, `field2`)
VALUES
    (1, 'field1 value 1', 'field2 value 1'),
    (2, 'field1 value 2', 'field2 value 2'),
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `id` = VALUES(`id`),
    `field1` = VALUES(`field1`),
    `field2` = VALUES(`field2`);
```

But i'ld feel more confortable using `db_update` instead of `db_query`.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example to update:

```
    $items = array(1,2);
    db_update('your_table')->fields(array(
      'update_field_one' => $to_update_one,
      'update_field_two' => $to_update_two,
      'updated' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))->condition('id', $items, 'IN')->execute();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this would set the same value for field one/two etc for every row, while i want to save a different value in each field for each row

Answer (score 0):

You try the code update:

```
foreach ($updates as $key => $value) {
  $fields = array('some_field' => $value);
  db_update('your_table')->fields($fields)->condition('some_id', $key)->execute();
}
```